# Cross Browser call using jsonp but returning XML

Tags: jquery, xml, cross-domain, jsonp, steam

I want to get the data returned from this URL using a purely Client side approach

http://steamcommunity.com/id/rahulkadukar/stats/TheElderScrollsVSkyrim/?tab=achievements&xml=1

This is my code as of now

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function()
    {

        var data;
        $('#New').click(function()
        {
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "http://steamcommunity.com/id/rahulkadukar/stats/TheElderScrollsVSkyrim/?tab=achievements&xml=1",
                dataType: "jsonp",
                success: readData(data)
            })

            function readData(data) 
            { 
                console.log(data);
            }
        });
    });
    </script>
```

Can someone tell me what I should do, so that I can get the data from Steam into a JSON variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't.

The point of the protection against XSS attacks is to ensure the server is willing to let its data be embedded in a page from another domain.

So all solutions, [JSONP (call of a javascript variable)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP) or [CORS headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP_access_control), involve a modification of the server, or to call the other domain server from yours in order to let only one domain be visible from the browser.

Comment: Since this is public data, it would be reasonable to ask Valve to serve it with CORS. That is the proper technical solution.